# How do I pipe an expression in Polars?

Tags: python-polars

How do you "pipe" an expression in Polars?

Consider this code:

```
def transformation(col:pl.Series)->pl.Series:
    return col.tanh().suffix('_tanh')
```

It'd be nice to be able to do this:

```
df.with_columns([
   pl.col('colA').pipe(transformation), 
   pl.col('colB').pipe(transformation), 
   pl.col('colC').pipe(transformation), 
   pl.col('colD').pipe(transformation), 
])
```

But I don't think Polars supports .pipe for Series / expressions.

The alternative is

```
df.with_columns([
   transformation(pl.col('colA')), 
   transformation(pl.col('colB')), 
   transformation(pl.col('colC')), 
   transformation(pl.col('colD')), 
])
```

But this gets messy (IMO) when you have arguments to the `transformation` function

## Edit:

I implemented this and it "works" for me

```
def _pipe(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

pl.Expr.pipe = _pipe
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically (like pandas) you'd apply `pipe` at the DataFrame level.

Especially in conjunction with lazy-eval, this would be equivalent to chaining expressions; your function will receive the underlying eager/lazy frame, along with any optional *args and **kwargs, and by making it `lazy()` you ensure that your chain of operations can still take advantage of the query optimiser and parallelisation.

For example:

```py
import polars as pl

# define some UDFs
def extend_with_tan( df ):
    return df.with_columns( pl.all().tanh().suffix("_tanh") )

def mul_in_place( df, n ):
    return df.select( (pl.all() * n).suffix(f"_x{n}") )

# init lazyframe 
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "colA": [-4], 
    "colB": [-2], 
    "colC": [10],
}).lazy()

# pipe/result
dfx = df.pipe( extend_with_tan ).pipe( mul_in_place,n=3 )
dfx.collect()

# ┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┐
# │ colA_x3 ┆ colB_x3 ┆ colC_x3 ┆ colA_tanh_x3 ┆ colB_tanh_x3 ┆ colC_tanh_x3 │
# │ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---          ┆ ---          ┆ ---          │
# │ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ f64          ┆ f64          ┆ f64          │
# ╞═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╡
# │ -12     ┆ -6      ┆ 30      ┆ -2.997988    ┆ -2.892083    ┆ 3.0          │
# └─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┘
```

- API Docs: [polars "pipe" method](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.pipe.html)

Answer (score 1):

As you've probably realized, adding custom methods in order to be able to do method chaining is unfortunately not a first-class citizen in python.

In polars, a canonical way that hopefully satisfies you is to instead write a function that returns an *expression*. You do this already (although the type hint is incorrectly set to `pl.Series`), but can save some space by giving a string argument to our transformation function:

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({"colA": [-4], "colB": [-2], "colC": [0], "colD": [2]})


def transformation(name: str | list[str]) -> pl.Expr:
    return pl.col(name).tanh().suffix("_tanh")


df1 = df.with_columns(
    [
        transformation("colA"),
        transformation("colB"),
        transformation("colC"),
        transformation("colD"),
    ]
)
```

I realise this doesn't quite do what you wanted, but perhaps the following will cheer you up a bit. Since `pl.col()` can take a list of column names, we can do the following:

```py
df2 = df.with_column(transformation(["colA", "colB", "colC", "colD"]))

assert df1.frame_equal(df2) # True
```

And we can even target all of them using a regular expression:

```py
# ^col\w+$ is a regular expression matching `col<anything>`
df3 = df.with_column(transformation("^col\w+$"))


assert df1.frame_equal(df3) # True
```

Comment: Thank you, that's really cool. I am also fairly happy with my pl.Expr.pipe = _pipe solution. I know it's "dangerous", but It's very helpful and not causing any name conflict at the moment.